# $.inArray not telling whether item is in array or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

### Context

I have an array that contains the indices of a few elements on a webpage. Another array contains all of the possible indices the elements could have. I want to iterate through the array of possible indices and check each value against the indices that exist on the page to see if any of the indices that could be on the page are not on the page. I find the indices on the page in this way:

```
var indices = $(".inputValue").map(function() {

    return $(this).attr("value");

}).get();
```

Which gives me this result when I `console.log(indices)`:

```
["0", "2", "3"]
```

The array of possible indices I want to check for is as follows:

```
var potentialIndices = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

I then want to take each value within `potentialIndices` and compare it to `indices`. In this case, `potentialIndices` contains the number 1 where `indices` does not.

### Problem

I want to show that the number 1 is in `potentialIndices` and not `indices`. I decided to use `$.inArray` and a `forEach` loop to go through each item in the `potentialIndices` array. This is the code I used:

```
potentialIndices.forEach(function(item, index) {

    if ($.inArray(potentialIndices, indices) > -1) {

        console.log("in array");

    } else {

        console.log("not in array");

    }

});
```

When I run this code, I get `not in array` in the console 4 times. The result should be "not in array" logging 1 time and "in array" logging 3 times. Is there something wrong with the code?

### Things I Have Tried

I already tried making `potentialIndices` strings instead of integers (`["0", "1", "2", "3"]`), which didn't change the outcome.

I also used a `for` loop to try to get a different result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < potentialIndices.length; i++) {

    if ($.inArray(potentialIndices[i], indices) > -1) {

        console.log("in array");

    } else {

        console.log("not in array");

    }

}
```

But I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also test with `.filter` or indeed, simply with `.forEach()`:

```js
const tarr=["0", "2", "3"], parr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

parr.filter(v=>tarr.indexOf(""+v)<0 && console.log(v+" is not in tarr."));

parr.forEach(v=>tarr.indexOf(""+v)<0 && console.log(v+" is not in tarr."));
```

In order for an element of `parr` to be found in `tarr` it needs to be converted to a string first by concatenating it with an empty string (`""+v`).

Comment: Apparently it was just a problem with the data type. Using `parseInt()` on the `indices` array fixed the problem for me. However, this response also worked well. I'll keep it in mind for future reference. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, after going over it again, this is the solution that worked. However, I used `parseInt()` on the `indices` array and took out string conversion, leaving v alone in the `indexOf()` method.